# how to Convert HTML characters like @amp; to their Proper Form in C#

Tags: c#

How to convert these characters to plain text?

> â„¢, Â ®, â„¢, ® and â€”

this problem occurs when I get a text from the website during scraping and store it into the database.
But it adds special characters and & like character.
I want to remove these all.

Comment: Define 'plain text'

Comment: You mean Html encode? Because thats the most plain text char you can get from them. It's decimal , hex, oct. html number or html code.. It's plain text representation of the char. Type "ascii/html table" in a search engine and use an determine what exactly you have as input and what you want as output. Then [edit] those information in your question

Comment: I also recommend reading [ask] and [mcve] as those guideline will help you build good/clear question.

Comment: this is my text "Pads &amp; Notebooks" and I want to remove &amp; from the text and other special characters which mentioned above.

Comment: Why do you need plain text?  If you are trying to load a TextBox use a RichTextBox which support special characters.

Comment: I got it from the website during scrapping and store into Database

Comment: is there is any function in c#? which help me to do this all

Answer (score 1):

you can use this:

```
Encoding.Convert(Encoding.Default, Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(myvalue));
```

Comment: I want to remove these type of characters   &#39;
&nbsp;
&rsquo;
Â®
â„¢
®
â€”
&mdash;
&nbsp;

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public static string RemoveUTFCharactes(this string input)
{
   string output = string.Empty;
   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
   {
      byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(input);
      output = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
   }
   return output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The short solution of your question is below
**if you have limited symbols you can use the Replace method in C# language, like this**

```
string symbol="this is the book @amp; laptop";
string formattedterm = symbol.Replace("@amp;","&");
```